# How to get data of all rows from a dynamically generated table by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm using `jQuery` and `django`

I have a dynamic table generated by `jQuery`, which holds the `email` field and `password` field and the delete button that could remove the row:

```
    $("button#genBtn").click(function() {

        var t = $("input#inputEmail").val();
        var p = $("input#inputPassword").val();
        var delBtn = $('<button class=\"btn btn-danger\">delete</button>');
        var row = $("<tr><td>" + t + "</td><td>" + p + "</td><td></td></tr>");

        $('td:last', $(row)).append(delBtn);

        $(delBtn).bind("click", deleteNode);

        $("table tbody").append(row);

    });
```

This is the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let say I'd like to get the data of all rows from this table, and post it to sever side. How could I do that?

Comment: FYI, you should append the rows to `$("table tbody")`, not `$("table")`.

Comment: And `<thread>` should be `<thead>`.

Comment: @Barmar amended according to your comments

Comment: @Barmar BTW, why could I append the rows even I use `$("table")` rather than `$("table tbody")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any additional libraries, something like this:

(1) get the data from the table

```
function getTableData()
{
    // Array of data we'll return
    var data = [];

    // Counter
    var i = 0;

    // Cycle through each of the table body's rows
    $('tbody tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        var tds = $(tr).find('td');
        // Check we've got two <td>s
        if (tds.length > 1) {
            // If we do, get their text content and add it to the data array
            data[i++] = {
                email: tds[0].textContent,
                password: tds[1].textContent
            }
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

(2) post it to the server

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: '', // Set the URL of whatever in Django will handle your post
    data: getTableData()
});
```

*However*, if I were attempting this task, I would achieve (1) by using Knockout, which would allow for a much better separation between view and viewmodel (or between template and view, you might think of them, as a Django user).  Great that you're using a decent server-side framework, would be a pity to end up with spaghetti code on the client!

Comment: I'd like to do both (1) and (2) in just one `click` method. How to do that? Just put `$.ajax()` within the `click`? I tried but failed. BTW, after a quick look at the `Knockout`, can't tell the advantages because I'm a newbie to `javascript` or `jquery`. I only have experience at back-end, like `java` or `scala`. would you elaborate more

Comment: Yes (1) and (2) can be put next to each other, in the same code block, I only put space between them in order to make it easier to read.  Can you say more about how you "tried but failed", in order for me to help?

Comment: As for the advantage of Knockout (or Angular, or, ...) is that it provides a separation between templates and data.  I'll put together a fiddle and post it here to illustrate how this would be done in your example.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2EF/
That should make the learning curve easier, I hope!
More generally: would you try to make a webserver in pure python?  No, you use Django.
From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/: "it’s sensible to separate content from presentation"
This applies in a client-side program just as much as in a server-side program.
Of course, do consider other JavaScript libraries / frameworks libraries as well.  Knockout is well-suited to this particular problem, but you might well find something better.  If you do, let me know about it :)

Comment: Thx. I prefer AngularJS